# elpy-goto-definition jump to the center of the terminal window

Tags: elpy

I was using [dumb-jump](https://github.com/jacktasia/dumb-jump) to go to the location where the identifier at point is defined. When it jumps to the function, jumped function shows up on the middle of the terminal window.

---

=> Instead when I use `elpy-goto-definition` it jumps to the function and shows it on the 1st line on the top of the terminal window.

**[Q]** Is it possible to make `elpy-goto-definition` to show the jumped function on the center of the terminal like `dumb-jump`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not beeing a user of elpy but looking at [elpys source code](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/blob/master/elpy.el), I would say you have several options to do this (there are proably more).

Calling `elpy-goto-definition` results in a call to `elpy-goto-location` which at its end calls `(recenter 0)` and this `0` is the culprit.

3 completely separate ways to change that:

*first*
 create a new function (my-elpy-goto-definition) which just calls `elpy-goto-definition` and then does `(recenter)` without that `0`. to use it you always call `my-elpy-goto-definition` instead of `elpy-goto-definition` (least intrusive solution, Problem: you need to redefine your shortcut keys)

*second*
copy and paste the whole function `elpy-goto-location` then remove the offending `0` and re-eval that defun, effectively replacing the old function with your modified one. (very intrusive solution, Problem: you will never automatically receive code updates/fixes to that function, you have to include them manually)

*third*
write an advice to either `elpy-goto-definition` or `elpy-goto-location` (depends on how globaly you want this behavior), which calls an `(recenter)` after that function has run. (medium intrusive solution, works automatic, without changing keybindings, I'd probably go with this).

Example code  for *third* (advicing `elpy-goto-location`):

```
(defun my-recenter-elpy-goto (&rest r)
  (recenter))

(advice-add #'elpy-goto-location :after #'my-recenter-elpy-goto)
```

Comment: I made a keybinding for `my-recenter-elpy-goto`, it gives following error `Wrong type argument: commandp, my-recenter-elpy-goto`

Comment: @alper `my-recenter-elpy-goto` is not meant to be bound to a key. the `advice-add` installs this function, so it will be called automatically

Comment: @alper I don't see a reason why this message should appear. You only need to put those 3 lines from the solution into your init.el and everything should work. No additional keybindings, no nothing...

Comment: `xref-pop-marker-stack` is for the get back, can I return into  center for it as well?

Comment: @alper probably, just try it. But there is also another way: via [setting a hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks.html#Setting-Hooks). The hook variable is named: `xref-after-return-hook`, use: `(add-hook 'xref-after-return-hook 'recenter)` I have not tested this.

Comment: @alper btw. do you know the `*scratch*` buffer? Go there, enter some valid lisp expression or variable name and press `C-j`. It is useful to quickly test settings or eval lisp code.